# Covariance with Function return Types

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding, covariance, contravariance

I have roughly the following Type Hierarchy, (I know that all edges on a NonPolygon will not be arcs.

[image]

I am attempting to do Extrusions on all PlaneRegions resulting in returned Solid objects. When I extrude a Polygon I want to return a Polyhedron. When I return a NonPolygon, I want to return a NonPolyhedron, which is also a solid.

```
public class PlaneRegion
{
    public IEnumerable<IEdge> Edges;

    public virtual Solid Extrude()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }  
}
```

I extend the above class with two derived classes that use different derived types of IEdge as Edges. And I would like to also have their extrude methods return different derivations of Solid objects.

```
public class Polygon: PlaneRegion
{

    public Polygon(List<LineSegment> passedSegments)
    {
        this.Edges = passedSegment;
    }

    public new Polyhedron Extrude()
    {
        List<LineSegment> segments = Edges as List<LineSegment>;

        foreach (var segment in segments)
        {
           //do stuff
        }

        return new Polyhedron(new List<Polygon>(){ this});
    }
}

public class NonPolygon: PlaneRegion
{

    public NonPolygon(List<Arc> passedArcs)
    {
        this.Edges = passedArcs;
    }

    public new NonPolyhedron Extrude()
    {
        foreach (var arc in Edges as List<Arc>)
        {
            //do stuff
        }

        return new NonPolyhedron(new List<NonPolygon>(){this});
    }
}
```

When I attempt the following code, I call the implementation of PlaneRegion Extrude() instead of the derived classes implementations. I cannot override the Extrude method in PlaneRegion because I have "Different" return types. What is the appropriate way to return a derived type from a function in a derived type? (If there is a way?)

Answer (score 0):

Use the shared base type of Solid as the return value, not Polyhedron. After all, the base Extrude method doesn't know or care whether what's returned is Polyhedron or NonPolyhedron. Note that you still return a Polyhedron object…it's just that the caller gets the object as a Solid. It can be cast back to a Polyhedron by the caller if for some reason it cares (but usually if you are using  polymorphism correctly, it won't).

Note: in your diagram, you have "Solid" inheriting "Solid". I assume that the subclass "Solid" was supposed to be "NonPolyhedron".